# Keyboard shortcut (or permanent setting) for fitting column width to longest filename in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, finder

I use the OS X Finder feature to expand/fit the column width to the longest filename a lot -- by double-clicking the two vertical bars at the bottom of the column border (in Snow Leopard) or the column border itself (in Lion).

Is there a keybaord shortcut for this?

Or perhaps even a permanent setting to make fitting column widths to the longest filename the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

[A list of available keyboard shortcuts for finder](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

The issue I can see it not being possible is because finder doesn't know which column you are trying to resize.

Although, if you `Alt+doubleclick` all columns in the window should resize. :)

Comment: I was thinking the shortcut would resize the current column when you have a column active due to typing the first few letters of a filename and/or using the arrow keys. Thanks though!